# How to monitor free memory using newrelic with/out buffers/cached

Tags: linux, memory, buffer, newrelic

I am evaluating newrelic for server monitoring and could not find how to monitor the memory used by the operating system to buffer files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it only monitors consumed memory by the non-root user.